# Laptop does not recognize usb loaded with kubuntu 17.04

Tags: boot

I am trying to boot from usb loaded with kubuntu 17.04 32bit iso image on asus x55 laptop. It seems that bios does not recognize that usb loaded with kubuntu image, as kaosx and elementary os booted just fine. The procedure had been done with rufus on windows and i chosed both ISO image and DD image as with other mentitoned distributions. I noticed that during usb image creation rufus downloaded syslinux files, but i don't know what that file contains. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you set the right partition mode (MBR or GPT for BIOS or UEFI) in that USB drive in Rufus? Did the USB name popup in boot menu after pressing F12?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use other tools that are more preferable than rufus for creating bootable Linux distros. Follow the instructions below again from scratch. Hope you will succeed:

1. Download Universal USB Installer from [here](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/Universal-USB-Installer/Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.7.8.exe). There are some other tools out there which are specially designed for Linux. [UNetbootin](https://github.com/unetbootin/unetbootin/releases/download/647/unetbootin-windows-647.exe) may be your another choice.
2. Download the iso image of your required version from [here](http://www.kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/). May be you have already done this. Even then I am providing the proper link if you did mistake previously.

   This is the direct link of Kubuntu 17.04 32 bit (Download size: 1.63 GB): http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/17.04/release/kubuntu-17.04-desktop-i386.iso.
3. Now open Universal USB Installer and follow on-screen instructions. Select the downloaded ISO as ISO image and you are done.